# Ms Access Selector read as string in the query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I want to have a wildcard search query in an Ms. Access form. But if I place the selector inside the quotes it would be a string, not selector.
my selector is `[Forms]![MyForm]![txtsearch]`
This is my query that is not using wildcard and quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE RefName LIKE [Forms]![MyForm]![txtsearch]
```

the above query works fine, as the selector wasn't a string.
But if i run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE RefName LIKE "*[Forms]![MyForm]![txtsearch]*"
```

It would return nothing, because the selector be a string
How can I use the selector inside quotes or wildcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MS Access requires that the pattern be a constant ("literal"), so you cannot do:

```
 WHERE RefName LIKE "*" & [Forms]![MyForm]![txtsearch] & "*"
```

This (or the equivalent) construct would be allowed in other databases.

Instead, you can use `instr()`:

```
WHERE instr(RefName, [Forms]![MyForm]![txtsearch]) > 0
```

Comment: That construct is allowed in MS Access.